# Working on background color radius in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to work on inserting radius for the whole background color what syntax or css should i use?

```
 <View style={{backgroundColor: "#BF3EFF", height: "20%", width: "100%",  }}>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btVGX.png)

Comment: use: `borderRadius:50%`

Comment: give the view that have the background a borderRadius property

Answer (score 0):

Many CSS props with a hyphen (kebab case) are refered in that style html prop in camel case, so:

```
font-size => fontSize
background-color => backgroundColor
border-radius => borderRadius
```